# iOS: How do I get a list of names out of an array of dictionaries?

Tags: ios, json, parsing, server

Im currently trying to read out Object from file from server:

```
 NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sharedSession];
NSString *string = @"http://myfile.php";
//NSLog(string); //CHECK

[[session dataTaskWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:string]
       completionHandler : ^(NSData *data,
                             NSURLResponse *response,
                             NSError *error) {
           if (data.length > 0 && error == nil) {
               NSError *jsonvar;
               NSDictionary *greeting = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:&jsonvar];
               NSLog(@"%@", greeting);

               dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                   NSDictionary *main = [greeting objectForKey:@"array"];
                   //self.beaconMajor.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [main objectForKey:@"name"]];

               });
           }
       }] resume];
```

}

This is the response i get when i do a NSLog:

```
array =     (
            {
        endDate = "0000-00-00";
        id = 3;
        name = ruben;
        startDate = "0000-00-00";
    },
            {
        endDate = "0000-00-00";
        id = 4;
        name = "hallo mama";
        startDate = "0000-00-00";
    },
            {
        endDate = "0000-00-00";
        id = 5;
        name = heyoo;
        startDate = "0000-00-00";
    },
            {
        endDate = "0000-00-00";
        id = 6;
        name = "Gerard Depardieu";
        startDate = "0000-00-00";
    }
);
```

Can anyone help me out how to read out for example the "names" of this Array ?

Thanks!

Comment: FYI - `main` should be `NSArray`, not `NSDictionary`.

Comment: do you need a first name from the array or the whole array of names?
If you need just the first occurrence then you need `NSDictionary *main = [[greeting objectForKey:@"array"] firstObject];`
If you need an array of distinct names from the array, you may find kvc helpful: `[greeting[@"array"] valueForKeyPath:@"@distinctUnionOfObjects.name"]`
see more here: http://nshipster.com/kvc-collection-operators/

Answer (score 1):

You can do it manually:

```
NSArray *main = [greeting objectForKey:@"array"];
for (NSDictionary *dict in main) {
    NSLog(@"name=%@", dict[@"name"]);
}
```

or you can use KVC to get all the names from the dictionaries within the array:

```
NSArray *main = [greeting objectForKey:@"array"];
NSArray *names = [main valueForKey:@"name"];
```

(When you use `valueForKey` on an array, it will call `valueForKey` on each contained object).